# Spring Data JPA - Query generation from method name using query parameters on REST call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I would like to use a REST end point, pass query parameters (a combination of qp1, qp2, qp3) to it, like for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/..../my-rest-endpoint?qp1=abc or 
http://localhost:8080/..../my-rest-endpoint?qp2=123 or 
http://localhost:8080/..../my-rest-endpoint?qp1=abc&qp2=123 or
...
```

For that I defined the REST endpoint like:

```
@GetMapping("/my-rest-endpoint")
public List<MyEntity> getMyEntities(WebRequest webrequest) {
    Map<String, String[]> params = webrequest.getParameterMap();

    String qp1 = params.containsKey("qp1") ? params.get("qp1")[0] : null;
    Long qp2 = params.containsKey("qp2") ? Long.valueOf(params.get("qp2")[0]) : null;
    String qp3 = params.containsKey("qp3") ? params.get("qp3")[0] : null;

    List<WebfitVehicleContract> result = webfitVehicleContractRepository.findByQp1AndQp2AndQp3(qp1, qp2, qp3);

    return result;
}
```

And in the JPA interface the method like:

```
List<MyEntity> findByQp1AndQp2AndQp3(@Nullable String qp1, @Nullable Long qp2, @Nullable String qp3);
```

But this approach yields as it looks like to a query generation which considers all query parameters:
    ... WHERE qp1 = ... AND qp2 = ... AND qp3 = ...

For example if I call it like:

```
http://localhost:8080/..../my-rest-endpoint?qp2=123
```

it looks like the query generation was: 
    ...WHERE qp1 = null AND qp2 = 123 AND qp3 = null

What I would like to achieve is, that only those query parameters which are present in the URL call, only whith those the query should be build.

If the call is with only qp1
    http://localhost:8080/..../my-rest-endpoint?qp1=abc

The generated query shall consider only qp1 and result in 
    ...WHERE qp1 = 'abc'

Is this possible with query generation from method names? Perhaps with some Annotations or similar.
Obviously I could define for any combination of query parameters a method in the JPA interface, but this approach seems not feasible. With 3 query parameters I would have to define 6 methods, with more query parameters even more.

And I don't wanted to write plain SQL, want to use the features of Spring Data JPA.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since your parameters are nullable, Change your repository method to have `Or` instead of `And`

```
List<MyEntity> findByQp1OrQp2OrQp3(@Nullable String qp1, @Nullable Long qp2, @Nullable String qp3);
```

Comment: This will work for the null case but not if all parameters are specified. I think @neblaz want to have results matching all of the criterias in this case

Comment: Correct, I want to reduce result set with given parameters, matching them, so AND is correct.

Comment: Using @Nullable was just assuming that that is the right approach. I thought, if a parameter is null, then it is not considered in the query generation, but unfortunately not.